# How to put a Lable on a Rectangle in Kivy

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I am quite a novice programming with kivy, and I just wanted to put a green rectangle under a label to make it look a little bit like a display. I've tried making a `label` and then, inside of it, a `canvas` with the rectangle, but when it's time to put them together, the `self.pos` doesn't put them on the same place... Here's part of the code:

```
'''.kv file'''
Label:
            id: s_label
            size:50,50
            text:'[font=Digital-7][color=D20000][size=24] S= [/color][/font][/size]'
            markup:True
            pos_hint:{'x':0.3,'y':-0.2}
            canvas:
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 0, 153, 0, 0.5
                RoundedRectangle:
                    pos: self.pos[0] , self.pos[1]
                    size: (self.width/6, self.width/16)
                    id: S_rect
```

The Label is inside a `FloatLayout`, but I don't know if that is relevant.
[this is what I get. See, the green rectangle is far away from the red S label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4z8K.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems with your code:

1. You must include `size_hint: None, None` in your `Label` in the `kv`. Without that, the `size` has no effect, and the `Label` fills its parent.
2. The `pos_hint:{'x':0.3,'y':-0.2}` positions the Label below the bottom of the parent. Try something like `pos_hint:{'x':0.3,'y':0.2}`.